# Three.js Shader color threshold

Tags: three.js, shader

I do not know how to correctly say, in general, the essence is, I found a bloom shader: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_unreal_bloom.html

It works fine, but a little not as it is necessary for me, it allocates only bright areas and highlights.

I need to highlight not the brightness, I need to highlight the intensity of the color.

For example:

[image: http://dt-byte.ru/fe3ba464.png]

In the picture I highlighted a circle where there should be a selection, have ideas how to do this?

Thanks in advance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `RGBtoHSV` function to check the hue, saturation, and value  of a pixel then take the distance from that to the actual color to decide to bloom or not

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17897228/128511):

```
vec3 rgb2hsv(vec3 c)
{
    vec4 K = vec4(0.0, -1.0 / 3.0, 2.0 / 3.0, -1.0);
    vec4 p = mix(vec4(c.bg, K.wz), vec4(c.gb, K.xy), step(c.b, c.g));
    vec4 q = mix(vec4(p.xyw, c.r), vec4(c.r, p.yzx), step(p.x, c.r));

    float d = q.x - min(q.w, q.y);
    float e = 1.0e-10;
    return vec3(abs(q.z + (q.w - q.y) / (6.0 * d + e)), d / (q.x + e), q.x);
}
```

Therefore

```
// PSEUDO CODE!

uniform vec3 targetHSV;   // supply hue, saturation, value in 0 to 1 range for each. 
                          // Red = 0,1,1

vec3 color = texture2D(renderTarget, uv).rgb;
vec3 hsv = rgb2hsv(color);
vec3 hueDist = abs(hsv.x - targetHSV.x);

// hue wraps
if (hueDist > 0.5) {
  hueDist = 1. - hueDist;
}

// 2x for hue because it's at most .5 dist?
float dist = length(vec3(hueDist * 2., hsv.yz - targetHSV.yz));

// now use dist < threshold or smoothstep or something to decide
// whether value contributes to bloom
```

Comment: Thanks, but just about the wrong way) the parameter (targetHSV) I will not specify, it will be taken from the pixel. 

And what I got: http://dt-byte.ru/ff02c45a.png

Comment: I'm only interested in this palette http://dt-byte.ru/f9750aa0.png, as there is no white or gray color there)

Comment: Thanks again) and I found where I was wrong, everything is working fine now.