# GLSL "No Matching Overloaded Function Found" (hsv2rgb)

Tags: glsl, shader, webgl

What obvious thing am I missing?  I'm trying to compile/run this vertex shader:

```c
// an attribute will receive data from a buffer
attribute vec2 a_position;

uniform vec2 u_resolution;

varying vec4 v_color;

// all shaders have a main function
void main() {
    // convert the position from pixels to 0.0 to 1.0
    vec2 zeroToOne = a_position / u_resolution;
    // convert from 0->1 to 0->2
    vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;
    // convert from 0->2 to -1->+1 (clip space)
    vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;
    gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace, 0, 1);
    vec3 c = hsv2rgb(vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5));
    /*temporary*/ v_color = gl_Position * 0.5 + 0.5;
    gl_PointSize = 1.0;
}

// All components are in the range [0…1], including hue.
vec3 hsv2rgb(vec3 c)
{
    vec4 K = vec4(1.0, 2.0 / 3.0, 1.0 / 3.0, 3.0);
    vec3 p = abs(fract(c.xxx + K.xyz) * 6.0 - K.www);
    return c.z * mix(K.xxx, clamp(p - K.xxx, 0.0, 1.0), c.y);
}
```

using code I found at [From RGB to HSV in OpenGL GLSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095909/from-rgb-to-hsv-in-opengl-glsl) but get the error:

> ```
> https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-boilerplate.html
> webgl-utils.js:66 *** Error compiling shader '[object WebGLShader]':ERROR: 0:19: 'hsv2rgb' : no matching overloaded function found
> ERROR: 0:19: '=' : dimension mismatch
> ERROR: 0:19: '=' : cannot convert from 'const mediump float' to 'highp 3-component vector of float'
> ```

The error is specific to the `hsv2rgb` call. I have tried a number of things, including making the parameter a variable (i.e. adding `vec3 v = vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)` and passing `v` into `hsv2rgb`), and making a skeleton `hbv2rgb` that simply returns its parameter. In the referenced SO post, I saw that another user seemed to have exactly the same problem, but I am properly passing in a `vec3` rather than 3 floats.

If it makes any difference, here is the fragment shader as well:

```c
// fragment shaders don't have a default precision so we need
// to pick one. mediump is a good default
precision mediump float;

varying vec4 v_color;

void main() {
    // gl_FragColor is a special variable a fragment shader
    // is responsible for setting
    gl_FragColor = v_color;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [OpenGL ES Shading Language 1.00 Specification - 6.1 Function Definitions](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.00.pdf#page=59&zoom=100,153,377):

> All functions must be either declared with a prototype or defined with a body before they are called.

Hence, you have to declare the function `hsv2rgb` before it is used the first time or you have to declare a function prototype:

```c
vec3 hsv2rgb(vec3 c);

void main() {
    // [...]

    vec3 c = hsv2rgb(vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5));

    // [...]
}

vec3 hsv2rgb(vec3 c)
{
    vec4 K = vec4(1.0, 2.0 / 3.0, 1.0 / 3.0, 3.0);
    vec3 p = abs(fract(c.xxx + K.xyz) * 6.0 - K.www);
    return c.z * mix(K.xxx, clamp(p - K.xxx, 0.0, 1.0), c.y);
}
```

Comment: That did it.  Thanks @Rabbid76!